# AI model to predict/generate person's image

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

I want to make a **model that predicts person's shape depending on his son's image**.

My plan is to create a dataset and each data point in it consists of two images; One for the father or mother and one for the son. Then make a model and train it with this dataset.

So when I give the model an image of a son, it predicts / generates / draws the father's image.

- **Is that is possible ?**
- **If yes, How can I make it ? ML ? Deep Learning ? Something else ?**

*I searched a lot but didn't find something helpful; So any ideas or opinions are welcomed.*

Comment: Take a look at generative adversarial networks (GANs), in particular at conditional GANs and image-to-image translation (Pix2Pix, CycleGAN), as well as style transfer (StyleGAN2).

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at them.